# Auth/Session not working on one page in Sails with Passport

Tags: node.js, sails.js, passport.js, passport-local

I have used passport to manage authentication in Sails. It is working bar one odd issue. If I check for a user in order to modify the nav bar

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            {{#if user}}
                <li>{{ user.username }}</li>
                <li><a href="/logout">Logout</a></li>
                User!
            {{else}}
                <li><a href="/login">Login</a></li>
            {{/if}}
        </ul>
```

The log in and go to / There is nothing there.
When I go to /login or /logout, both of which use the same template and share the code above, I get both conditions being met.

[image: screenshot]

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you add template inheritance or trying to log users on home page, to check if he exist?

Comment: Hello. I am not sure I understand the template inheritance bit. The user object just doesn't exist. Looking online it appears to be a common thing for passport and sails but I have yet to see an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, the issue was that policies in Sails are only applied to Controllers, not views.

[Sails Docs](http://sailsjs.org/#!/documentation/concepts/Policies)

The solution was to create a pages controller, route a method to the home page view and then apply the following policy to it. It passes it by passport but doesn't restrict access.
PageController.js

```
    module.exports = {
    home: function (req, res) {
        res.view();
    }
};
```

policies.js

```
    '*': ['passport'],

  PageController: {
    '*': ['passport', true]
  }
```